# Blogger.com: Changing Header to slideshow with HTML & Java

Tags: html, css, templates, header, blogger

I am currently working on a new template and I want to change my header into a slideshow. If I knew how, I would love it to look like the following:

http://www.masha-sedgwick.com/de/

Unfortunately, I am a noop when it comes to webdesign so I am watching tutorials after tutorials and I am trying to personalize/adjust it to come to an adequate result.

So, at first I tried my best to put the following tutorial into practice. As you will see, there are still some bugs that have to be fixed.

automatic slideshow tutorial:
https://codepad.co/snippet/0p7cAgm1

that's my test website:
https://bt2dtest.blogspot.de/

What has to be fixed?;

(1) size of the header space has to be adjusted to the photos

-> *However, I am failing to find where I can change it in the HTML. If someone has a clue, please help me out.*

(2) As my photos have a different size to the ones in the tutorial, the loop is off.

-> *How can I change that? (I'd be more than happy if anyone can explain the mechanism to me so I actually get what I am doing.)*

(3) as extra I'd love the slider to work over the whole site and have some extra space from top.

-> *Again, I haven't found the line where I can change it and kindly ask you to help me.*

I am thankful for any helpful answer.

X,
Elisa

***Here's the HTML/CSS my blog consists of:***

https://www.file-upload.net/download-12829883/betterthan2day7.xml.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you don't have to design slider from scratch, but use one of many predesigned libraries instead. The most popular are:
- [Owl Carousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/),
- [Slick Slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/).

Although second one seems to be abandoned, it still seems better to me. Both of these sliders will automatically display images in a form of slider.

Now - depending on your coding knowledge, it may require some work to create a slider. First of all you need to incude both slider and `jQuery` libraries in your template header (this is not an image/blog name, this is part of template code named `header`). Find `</head>` tag and place following codes right before it:

```
<script src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js' type='text/javascript'/>
<link href='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css' type='text/css' />
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js' type='text/javascript' />
```

First code loads `jQuery` library that is crucial to run your slider. Second code is a basic CSS style for slider, while third is the slider itself.

Now the fun part - grab some images, upload them to Blogger or outside image hosting service and collect their addresses. Then go to "Layout" section on your Blogger dashboard, and add new "HTML/JavaScript" widget in a place where you want your slider to appear. Use following code:

```
<div class="image-slider">
    <a href="POST_ADDRESS"><img src="YOUR_IMAGE" /></a>
    <a href="POST_ADDRESS"><img src="YOUR_IMAGE" /></a>
    <a href="POST_ADDRESS"><img src="YOUR_IMAGE" /></a>
    <a href="POST_ADDRESS"><img src="YOUR_IMAGE" /></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('.image-slider').slick({
          slidesToShow: 3,
          slidesToScroll: 1,
          autoplay: true,
          autoplaySpeed: 2000,
          arrows: false,
          dots: false,
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .image-slider {
        margin-top: 25px;
    }
    .image-slider .slick-slide {
        margin: 0 3px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .image-slider a {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .image-slider img {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
</style>
```

Let me know if it worked :)

Thanks,
Luca

Comment: Hi Luca, first of all, thanks a lot for your help. The slider actually works, however, I was looking for an automatic one. (like the 9th one on the website you sent me: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ ) I'm not quite sure how to include / change that, since, as far as I can see, you didn't use the instruction on the website. Furthermore, I wanted to have about 5px betweem the photos in the slider - do you think we can make this happen, too? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi Elisa, Now it's just a matter of adding some options. I've edited my slider code above, so it looks like 9th example, with a bit of spacing too. I've used margin value of 3px simply because it's being added on both sides of single slide. Adding 3px on the right side of first slide and 3px on the left side of second slide, makes it 6px. Why not 5px? Because you'd have to use 2.5px margin on each side.

Comment: I can't edit my previous comment, sorry. If you find my answer useful, kindly mark it as correct, I would be extremely greatful! :)

Comment: Hi Luca, alright, so if I want to make any adjustments, I simply add it to the "HTML/Java Script" Widget? Unfortunately, it doesn't work at all. The pictures are now arranged in an weird shape and it's also not sliding at all. Just take a look: https://bt2dtest.blogspot.de (I'm sorry for keeping you busy with my concern & appreciate your effort!)

Comment: Concerning the marking of your answer, I already gave you an upvote or is there another option?

Comment: Don't worry, hope we'll make it work :) Yes, to keep things simple, you can add all the code to a single "HTML/JavaScript" widget (except for the part where I asked you to put some code in template code directly). Could you add 4th image to your slider? I'll update my answer above in a minute, but it's just about adding another <img> tag inside slider container. As for the marking answer as correct - you should be able to click a check mark right under voting option on the top-left side of the answer post.

Comment: HI Luca, thanks a lot! That looks great! Just tow other questions: (1) If I want the pictures to be bigger, I simply add width: 300px height: ?? px, after  <img src="YOUR_IMAGE" /> ? (2) Is it possible to delete the 'nest' and 'previous' button in the slider now that it's an automatic slide? (3) Is there an option that I can link the photos to a post of my blog, or

Comment: (3) Is there an option that I can link the photos to a post of my blog, or add a caption that is linked to one of my posts? Sorry again, for asking you so many questions! (now I was struggling with changing my comment oops!)

Comment: (1) Making pictures bigger may require more work, I'd suggest starting with presized pictures, ideally at least 1200px wide (for example a 400 x 1200px size).  (2) Sure, I will update my code in a minute. (3) It's possible as well, however in the beginning your images may disappear, but we'll see about that when you apply new code :)

Comment: Again I can't edit my comment as 5-minute mark has passed... I gave you image size for one slide only, but since you have multiple slides displayed at once, an image of 400x300 would be good (or 300x400, if you want to use portrait format).

Comment: Perfect, so the buttons are gone now. I changed the photos to a width of 800 px, however, they are still displayed the same - guess the presizing doesn't matter or what did I forget? I'm so thankful for your help!

Comment: Be aware that photos are scaled down at the same ratio for width and height, so that the narrower your current pictures are, the less their height is. Also I've updated the CSS code above so that your slider fits in blog area.

Comment: Hi Luca, yeah I totally get the system. Since you changed width to 100%, the slider should adapt if I choose to take wider photos, right? Anyway, for whatever reason, it's not working anymore, after changing the code. And what do you mean by the slider fits the post area now? I kinda liked that the slider was seen over the whole page or do you mean something different? Thanks again!

Comment: Hi Elisa, actually there was an error in the code that caused slider to display at bigger width than the container it was placed in. Currently it should not exceed the white area of your blog. Not sure why it stopped working, I've changed the code above to the last working state.

Comment: Hi Luca, espacially that was what i wanted! :) (the slider to be bigger width than the container it was placed in - it is supposed to be seen over the whole page, breaking out of the blog area/contaimer) Even so, you changed the code back to an earlier state, it's still not working :( maybe it's because the photos are linked now?

Comment: Hi Elisa, okay, I've found a fix. Please update your code with the one above (I've added some CSS).

Comment: Hi Luca, alright, thanks a lot. I adjusted all the settings so it matches my idea now. One question at last; if I want to have some space between top of the website and slider, I change that in the HTML, too or create another widget? I'd love the space to be about 25px. Thanks again!

Comment: You need only a small change in CSS code above, look for "margin-top: 25px" property. You can adjust it to any value you prefer.